# Load a whole directory of css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is two-fold would it be possible to load a whole directory of css or javascript? And would there be any advantage to doing so?

Example - For an ecommerce store you might have a bunch of additional css and javascript that is required for functionality/styling. Putting all the javascript files required in `js/checkout` directory and then importing the whole directory would seem to be more streamlined than calling each one individually.

Is it possible to do this? 
Or is there some reason it would be a bad idea?

Comment: Why not just include them all in your HTML? Alternatively you probably have to use some server side script to read all the files in your directory and output them to the browser.

Comment: I didn't want to include them all in the html because it creates a lot of 'bloat.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than loading them individually, add a build step to your deployment so that you can minify all of the CSS and JavaScript into two files.  Then serve those two files so that only send two things instead of potentially many many more.

Additionally, although creating a build system from scratch can be "fun", you may want to look into some of the build tools that already have a big following.  I've used [Dojo Toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) before and it works well.  You would get [Asynchonous Module Definitions (AMD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) from using it which could also reduce the number of requests you need to make.  Another particular JS build system that I've heard mentioned quite often (although I haven't used it yet) is [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/).

Note, there is a trade off choice.  Using AMD can help you reduce the overall number of requests that you make to where you only load the scripts that you use.  Compare this to downloading one gigantic JS file that holds all possible scripts.

### One Mega Script

If you have 100 **5kb** script files, one mega minified script could (if there were no size gains from semicolons, name mangling, and linebreak removal) be **500kb**.  It would take one request to receive that script and let's pretend that a request takes **1kb** on average.  That means that, in total, the mega script would cost you **101kb**.

### AMD

Now consider the cost if you use AMD.  Let's say on a particular page you only use 7 of those **5kb** scripts and that the request still only takes 1kb.  Let's also pretend that the overhead of the AMD library is **10kb**.  That page would cost **52kb** `((7 * (1kb + 5kb)) + 10kb)`

As you can see, using the AMD method rather than the build will cause for more requests, but give you a net gain in terms of cost.  This *ALSO* doesn't account for caching things that have already been loaded before.

Also, if a user navigates your entire site, visiting every single page, causing every single script to be downloaded, then it will have cost you **610kb** `(100 * (5kb + 1kb)) + 10kb`.  However, if you go with the minified script, it would only cost you **501kb**.

Oh, and don't think that AMD vs One Mega Script has an impact on minification.  In both cases, minification is helpful in reducing request size.

Comment: Wow, that's a great idea! It would also reduce the number of requests to the server. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @NateW I added a little bit more detail on some build systems and another thing to think about with respect to packing all your scripts together.